# Multiple Inheritances

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm supposed to find out what object is p pointing to and write out the functions. And also I'm not supposed to use *virtual*.  I've been stuck on this for a while and would appreciate any help.

```
class Employee ;
class Secretary : public Employee ;
class Manager : public Employee ;
class Director : public Manager ;
// ...
void f( Employee *p) {
// what class does p belong to?
}
```

Comment: You can use the result of [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) to figure out what derived class you have, however your class needs to have a vtable (i.e. at least one virtual function) for `dynamic_cast` to work.

Comment: What do destructors have to do with this?

Comment: if you are not supposed to use virtual function, this is not acceptable. Otherwise here you go:http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a25ce82b62981f0

Comment: You can use `#include<type_traits>` which has a class template `is_same` which will help you know the type. I'm suggesting this because you are nt using `virtual function`

Comment: @Ankit , `is_same` will not help here, as it compares two _already known_ types, and the problem is to _know_ a real type of object. Best way is to add a field to Emloyee which will tell actual type, C-style.